# pandas loc behaves differently with row filter

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas loc method when used with row filter throws an error

```
test[test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)]
```

> IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index
> of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

whereas the same code without row filter works fine

```
test[test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)]
```

steps to reproduce

```
test=pd.DataFrame({"holiday":[0,0,0],"weekday":[1,2,3],"workingday":[1,1,1]})
test[test.loc[:,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)] ##works fine
test[test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)] ##fails
```

I am trying to understand what is the difference between these two which makes one fail whereas the other one succeed

Answer (score 1):

So the basic syntax is `DataFrame[things to look for, e.g row slices or columns]`
With that in mind, you are trying to filter your dataframe `test` with the following commands (these are the code snippets in the brackets):

`test.loc[:,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)`

This returns `True` for every row in the dataframe and therefore the "filter" returns the entire dataframe

`test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)`

This part itself is working and it is doing so by slicing the rows 0 and 1 and then applying the lambda function. Therefore, the "filter" consists of True in only 2 rows. Now the point is, that there is no value for the third row and this causes your error: The indices of the dataframe that has to be sliced (3 rows) and the boolean Series used to slice it (2 values) don't match.

Solving this problem depends on what you actually want as your output, i.e. whether the lambda function is supposed to be applied only to a subset of the data or whether you want only a subset of the results being retrieved to work with.

Comment: Thanks Ben , I am trying to apply a function on a subset of data based on a condition. I was hoping that the `test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']]` would give a new subset of df and i can apply on it. Could you give a bit more clarity as to how we can achieve it.

Comment: The `test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']]` does exactly what you expect it to do: it takes a subset of the data and in the next step the apply function is applied to this subset. The problem with your code is that you used the result of this function applied to a subset of the data to slice the entire dataframe (via the outer `test[...]`) and here the length of both did not match. Maybe try the following: `test['result'] = test.loc[0:1,['holiday','weekday']].apply(lambda x:True,axis=1)` and then look at `test` to see what happens and if that is what you actually want.